# How to Hide Div then visit Url on One Click

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would I go about setting a link to perform certain functions like hide div then go to destined url

something like this

$(document).ready(function(){
 $("a").click(function(){
       $("#div1").slideUp("slow");
       $("#div2").slideUp("slow");
       // then go to index.html
   });
});

This is my setup.

```
<script type="text/javascript">   $(document).ready(function(){
     $("a").click(function(){
     $("#one").hide("slow");
     $("#two").hide("slow" , function(){
     window.location (index.html);
       });
    });   });    </script>   

<div id="one"> some content </div>

<div id="two"> some content </div>

<a href="#">BUTTON HERE</a>
```

It only performs the hide function, if I replace the url in the html it perform the url only. I must be doing something Wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Location" is actually a property of the window object, *not* a method. This means you need to assign it with =,  instead of passing it as a parameter with (). Try this code out:

```
$("a").click(function(event){ 
    event.preventDefault();
    var url  = $(this).attr("href");
     $("#div1").slideUp("slow"); 
     $("#div2").slideUp("slow", function(){
       window.location=url;
    }); 
 });
```

Also, the default behavior of a link is to go to a URL, and it's going to run that behavior unless you stop it with something like "return false;". While setting the href to "#" won't take a user anywhere, it WILL scroll them to the top of the page, which could be annoying. Better to just return false it.

Comment: I added the url  = line as a bonus for users without JS - if they click a "#" link, nothing will happen, which would suck. Instead, you can leave them a normal, working link that goes to http://whatever and just grab that HREF using jQuery for the window.location assignment. Everybody wins!

Comment: return false works most of the time, but if you really want to cancel the link click, a bit of preventDefault() helps too - http://docs.jquery.com/Events/jQuery.Event#event.preventDefault.28.29

Comment: oh, +1 btw, you're the only one to mention cancelling of the link click, which is likely to be Anders' problem :-)

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the preventDefault() tip, I hadn't heard of that! Seems like a more widely-applicable answer to problems like this.

Answer (score 3):

try to put the redirect as callback to be executed after the last slideup:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("a").click(function(){ 
        $("#div1").slideUp("slow"); 
        $("#div2").slideUp("slow", function(){
           window.location(url); // or window.location.replace(url);
        }); 
    }); 
});
```

Comment: This is correct, however I question the need to do an animation before redirecting. Sort of like delaying the inevitable with unnecessary animation.

Comment: this is exactly what the callback is doing. After the last slideup is finished the redirect is called. check the documentation here http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/slideUp

Comment: I have adjusted my code to fit I thought, I edited it above, I wonder what I am doing wrong. yes Ian the animation probably isnt neccesary in most cases, but what I am trying to achieve I would like it.

Comment: @Elzo, I know what the callback is doing and what's its for, I was just commenting on whether such an effect is actually useful.

Comment: I don't really question the design issue.You can attach a callback directly to the hide() method without doing any animation. http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/hide.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is probably about right. Here's what you need to go to a new URL:

```
top.location.href='someURL';
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in JQuery to redirect from current page to some other page, but JavaScript has it location object, you can use it like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("a").click(function(){ 
        $("#div1").slideUp("slow"); 
        $("#div2").slideUp("slow"); 
        window.location(url); // or window.location.replace(url);

    }); 
});
```

You can read more abot redirection in JavaScript here: [How to redirect to another webpage in JavaScript/jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/redirect-page-in-jquery)

Comment: actually this will redirect before you can see the animations. window.location call will be executed before the slideUp will finish

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to set location in javascript? What's wrong with just putting in in the href attribute?